# HBase reverse scan error

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, hadoop2

this works well:

```
scan = new Scan(startRow, stopRow);
```

this throws exception sometimes:

```
scan = new Scan(stopRow, startRow);
scan.setReversed(true);
```

throwing exception while traffic is 100 req/s. there are actually no timeouts, exception is fired immediately for 1-10% requests

hbase: 0.98.12-hadoop2;
hadoop: 2.7.0;
cluster in AWS, 10 datanodes: d2.4xlarge

I think it's maybe related with this issue but I'm not using any filters http://apache-hbase.679495.n3.nabble.com/Exception-during-a-reverse-scan-with-filter-td4069721.html

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: Failed after retry of OutOfOrderScannerNextException: was there a rpc timeout?
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractClientScanner$1.hasNext(AbstractClientScanner.java:94)
        at com.socialbakers.broker.client.hbase.htable.AbstractHtableListScanner.scanToList(AbstractHtableListScanner.java:30)
        at com.socialbakers.broker.client.hbase.htable.AbstractHtableListSingleScanner.invokeOperation(AbstractHtableListSingleScanner.java:23)
        at com.socialbakers.broker.client.hbase.htable.AbstractHtableListSingleScanner.invokeOperation(AbstractHtableListSingleScanner.java:11)
        at com.socialbakers.broker.client.hbase.AbstractHbaseApi.endPointMethod(AbstractHbaseApi.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.socialbakers.broker.client.Route.invoke(Route.java:241)
        at com.socialbakers.broker.client.handler.EndpointHandler.invoke(EndpointHandler.java:173)
        at com.socialbakers.broker.client.handler.EndpointHandler.process(EndpointHandler.java:69)
        at com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.server.Dispatcher.process(Dispatcher.java:196)
        at com.socialbakers.broker.client.RejectableRunnable.run(RejectableRunnable.java:38)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: Failed after retry of OutOfOrderScannerNextException: was there a rpc timeout?
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.loadCache(ClientScanner.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.next(ClientScanner.java:333)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractClientScanner$1.hasNext(AbstractClientScanner.java:91)
        ... 15 more
        Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.OutOfOrderScannerNextException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.OutOfOrderScannerNextException: Expected nextCallSeq: 2 But the nextCallSeq got from client: 1; request=scanner_id: 27700695 number_of_rows: 100 close_scanner: false next_call_seq: 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.scan(HRegionServer.java:3231)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:30946)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2093)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor16.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.loadCache(ClientScanner.java:375)
        ... 17 more
        Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.OutOfOrderScannerNextException): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.OutOfOrderScannerNextException: Expected nextCallSeq: 2 But the nextCallSeq got from client: 1; request=scanner_id: 27700695 number_of_rows: 100 close_scanner: false next_call_seq: 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.scan(HRegionServer.java:3231)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:30946)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2093)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.call(RpcClient.java:1457)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1661)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1719)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:31392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:173)
        ... 21 more
```

Comment: there might be something abuot your error here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-11295.  try to increase the  the rpc timeout `hbase.rpc.timeout`

Comment: No it's not the case. Sometimes fails scan which hits only a few rows(less than 100) so it's definitely not a long running scan and fails immediately not after 60 seconds(hbase.rpc.timeout). But thank you for reply

Comment: do you use randome start/end row or does it always fail on the same start/end row?

Comment: random. when i've tried to call some failed requests manually they've always passed with no error

Comment: related issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-15757